# Getting CAMERA ON and CAMERA OFF toast messages

Tags: android

By registering for BroadcastReceiver i can  get SCREEN ON and SCREEN OFF toast messages , when device screen is swithced ON/OFF. In the same way, can i get CAMERA ON and CAMERA OFF toast messages, when device camera button is clicked?

I used below source code to get SCREEN ON/OFF toast messages.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

BroadcastReceiver mybroadcast = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    // When Event is published, onReceive method is called
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i("[BroadcastReceiver]", "MyReceiver");

        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
            Log.i("[BroadcastReceiver]", "Screen ON");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SCREEN ON",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
            Log.i("[BroadcastReceiver]", "Screen OFF");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SCREEN OFF",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    registerReceiver(mybroadcast, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON));
    registerReceiver(mybroadcast, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF));
}
```

Comment: What devices have a camera that you "open" or "close"?

Comment: @CommonsWare When i click on camera , "CAMERA ON" toast message should appear. When i close it, "CAMERA OFF" toast message should appear

Comment: What does "click on camera" mean? What does "close it" mean?

Comment: @CommonsWare How to list idle time of other applications installed on my android phone?